# Can't understand why strlen(char*) works [homework]

Tags: c

I have to use a recursive function that, given a string, says if it is palindrome or not.

I don't have any problem with this excercise, but I really can't understand why this code does what asked. In particular, I don't know why the strlen(char*) function doesn't throw an exception (i know that it is an OOP concept, but I don't know how to explain myself) like IndexOutOfRange

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
bool IsPalindrome(char str[],int index){
 if (index>0){
    if (str[index]==str[strlen(str)-1-index])
       return IsPalindrome(str,index-1);
    else
       return false;
 }
 else{
    if (str[index]==str[strlen(str)-1])
       return true;
    else
       return false;
 }
}

int main()
{
char A[100]; 
gets(A);
if (IsPalindrome(A,strlen(A)))
    printf("palindrome");
else
    printf("not palindrome");
getch();
return 0;
}
```

why don't I have to put:

```
 if (IsPalindrome(A,strlen(A)-1))
```

and it works anyway?

I'm using! Orwell's Dev-C++ with TDMGCC compiler 64-bit

Comment: You're already subtracting 1 in your `IsPalindrome` function.

Comment: @maxpesa: So, what do you see as a problem in this case? Why do you expect `IsPalindrome(A,strlen(A)-1)` to be necessary, as opposed to `IsPalindrome(A,strlen(A))`? Why do you think the latter is wrong? You talk about "`strlen` throwing an exception", but I don't see a single instance where it could possibly run into any problems. What specific call to `strlen` are you talking about and why do you think it is problematic?

Comment: if i use the string "hello", strlen's value is 6, then in str[index], i should get an error because str has "blocks" from 0 to 5

Comment: He's already subtracting 1, but in the _initial_ call, `index` is given a value of `strlen(A)`, so he would expect the line `str[index] == ...` to crash since he's forgetting / unaware that `str[index]` is the null terminator.

Comment: @maxpesa: That is false. "hello" is a string consisting of 6 characters indexed from 0 to 5. The last character (index 5) stores the terminating `\0` value.

Comment: @AndreyT, I didn't know how to call this type of error

Comment: What happens if you pass a string of length 0, or length 1?

Comment: @maxpesa: It does not matter what you call it. My question is: where do you see a problem and why?

Comment: I think the "IndexOutOfRange exception" discussion isn't really relevant - in C, this would generally be a segmentation fault, whereas in e.g. Java it would throw an exception.

Comment: @AndreyT, so it compares '\0' and 'h'

Comment: More or less. You end up comparing `'\0'` with whatever the `char` _before the first char in the string_ contains - see my and @Paul's answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code might cause an exception, and the fact that it works as expected is pure luck.

You're calling the function for the first time with the argument `index` = `strlen(str)`. Then, you're doing `str[strlen(str)-1-index]` which is equivalent to `str[-1]`.

`str[strlen(str)]`, as CmdrMoozy pointed out, is always null, so for the function to succeed, the byte before the string (which is not guaranteed to be even readable) must be null as well.
Apparently this situation is quite common in your environment, but of course it's not reliable.

Answer (score 2):

In C, strings are **null-terminated**. This means that, say for the string:

`"Hello, world!"`

There is an extra character at the end, namely `\0`, like this:

`"Hello, world!\0"`

The purpose of this is so e.g. the `strlen` function can compute the length of a string, without causing a *segmentation fault* or whatever. It simply loops through the string, and it knows that it's done when it sees that `'\0'` character.

So when you say `str[strlen(str)]`, you are looking at that null-terminator, which isn't really "part of the string" in some sense, but you do have that memory allocated so your program doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how strlen(char*) would be able to throw an IndexOutOfRange exception
All strlen(char*) will do is take a pointer, increment the pointer and a counter until *ptr == 0 at which point it will return the counter.

There is no concept of bounds involved in any of this. If your memory looked like

```
“ABC\0CDE\0DEF\0”
```

you could well ask for strlen() at any point in that buffer and that would be a legit operation

If your question is more along the lines of why doesn’t an “out of bounds” pointer access cause an exception, as say

```
myPointer[24]
```

when myPointer is

```
char* myPointer = “ABC”
```

That is because in C/C++ pointers are not bounds checked. myPointer[24] is the same as 24[myPointer] and that just means take the value of myPointer and increase it by

```
24*sizeof(*myPointer)
```

If you want bounds checking, you can write your own wrapper class around a pointer, and then pass that (pointer,size) pair around, override operator[] and make it throw exceptions if the index is >= size